# CakePHP editing form url breaks routing

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code to create a form in my app:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action'=>'edit')); ?>
```

and it has a route like:

```
Router::connect('/settings', array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'edit'));
```

However the action is wrong...

```
<form action="/users/edit/6" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

If I put the form to defaults with:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>
```

then it fixes the routing issue, but why does specifying parameters break the routing???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify in the create() parameters an actual URL - it will map to that url! The routes config doesn't map backwards. For example - if you visit `/settings`, it will load `/edit` page with the url still showing `/settings`. But if you visit `/edit`, it will show the url and will load the page `/edit`.

So if you want your form action to map to /settings, don't specify a url or use the url option `array('url' => '/settings')`